# This jsonp should be working so easily, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am trying to use asynchronous jsonp to display live prices on a webpage:

```
function addscript () {
    var url = "http://wdcticker.com/api/ticker?callback=updatePrices" + "&random=" + (new Date()).getTime();
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
    newScript.setAttribute("src",url);
    newScript.setAttribute("id","jsonp");
    var oldScript = document.getElementById("jsonp");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    if (oldScript == null) {
        head.appendChild(newScript);
    } else {
        head.replaceChild(newScript, oldScript);
    }
    console.log('done');

}

function updatePrices(result){
    alert('got here');
    $('#wdcusd').text(result.wdc_usd_avg);
    $('#wdcbtc').text(result.wdc_btc_avg);
}
```

The `addscript` function is called successfully every 10 seconds.   The callback function `updatePrices()` is not being called.  The error my console is showing is:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>
> ```
> "btc_e_btc_set": true,
> ```

even though the json at http://wdcticker.com/api/ticker passes json lint perfectly.  What am I doing wrong!!?  This should be so simple!

Comment: The service doesn't return JSONP (it returns JSON), so you cannot use JSONP. Check the service's API documentation if they support JSONP and how to enable it. If they don't support it, maybe there are other options to access the data from client-side JavaScript. If not, you are out of luck (you'd have to create your own server side service which requests the data).

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please explain to me the difference between returning jsonp and regular json?  I thought it was the same format, just different technique with how to call it?

Comment: JSON is just a data format. JSONP is more of a technique of how to retrieve data. As you've already done it in your code, JSONP is actually the inclusion of an external JavaScript file, which contains one function call: `someCallback(/* data */);`. Hence the response from the server must be valid JavaScript. JSON by itself is not valid JavaScript however and thus you get that error.

Comment: Thank you Felix! I feel pretty dumb now it was so obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If http://wdcticker.com/api/ticker?callback=updatePrices supported `JSONP` you would expect to see this as the response at that url:

```
updatePrices({
  // JSON here
});
```

Instead, it simply returns raw JSON like this:

```
{
  // JSON here
}
```

So it would appear that the server you are trying to connect to does not support `JSONP`, and server side support is required.  You cannot use `JSONP` with *any* `JSON` API, the API server must explicitly support and allow `JSONP`.